# background-image for firefox in CSS3 animations

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation, keyframe

I am making keyframe animation in CSS. The animation seems to be working very well in Chrome as the -webkit syntaxes are supported.

```
@-webkit-keyframes title_toggle 
{
from { background-image:url(images/title.png); }
75%{ background-image:url(images/title_hover.png); }
to { background-image:url(images/title.png); }
}
```

I tried the code below for Firefox, but its not working

```
@-moz-keyframes title_toggle {
from { background-image:url(images/title.png); }
75%{ background-image:url(images/title_hover.png); }
to { background-image:url(images/title.png); }
}
```

Please let me know I would this work in FF.

This is the CSS part.

```
@-moz-keyframes title_toggle {
from { background-image:url(images/title.png); }
75%{ background-image:url(images/title_hover.png); }
to { background-image:url(images/title.png); }
}

.title{
    width:40%;
    height: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 5%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation-name: title_toggle;
    -webkit-animation-duration:5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
     -moz-animation-name: title_toggle;
     -moz-animation-duration:5s;
     -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
```

And this is the HTML

```
<div class="title"></div>
```

Comment: which version of firefox are you testing on?

Comment: 15.0.1 something! I just downloaded it yesterday...

Comment: this should work, syntax is perfect..are you sure it is failing?

Comment: Yes... wait let me post complete CSS and HTML.

Comment: The website is working at http://aspspider.org/samarth

Check it in chrome and firefox

Comment: sorry, not able to make out as a developer am using old browsers, so...but your syntax looks good, no reason for the animation to fail..btw your website background is too heavy ..

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal the demo website you provided doesn't have a background animation for FF. Probably it's a webkit-only feature at the moment, and they rely on a javascript fallback

Comment: @GionaF Does my CSS/HTML lack anywhere? I am tired of trying! Is there any other way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Well, i see you've a duplicate background-size: 100% 100%; declaration. Apart from that, it seems ok. Probably, it's just not supported yet by FF. You can try some workarounds like: http://blog.w3conversions.com/2011/03/changing-a-background-image-with-css3-transitions/ or rely on JavaScript/jQuery for FF and IE

Comment: that is actually -moz-background-image: 100% 100%;
Thanks, i'll try.

Comment: It seems like some of the Animations functions do not work in FF. The `Hover to Pulsate` demo on this page, http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animations/, doesn't work in FF but works fine in Chrome.

Comment: did you tried instead of 'from' '75' 'to' to use '0%' '75%' '100%'?

Comment: @sarcastyx: The **Hover to Pulsate** is working in my FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about the lack of cross-fade interpolation between different images, that's a very new addition to the spec that's not widely supported yet.

Comment: I think that is what I am doing. I have created two images, showing one initially and then changing over to another one and then changing back to original. Is there any other way to achieve the same effect? Please see the website http://aspspider.org/samarth for the demo, in chrome. The title of the website in the first quarter is what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because Firefox does not support animations on background images. Background-image is not animatable. Chrome has its own implementation but you won't get it working Firefox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties