# CSS3 Compatibility Issues

Tags: google-chrome, css, animation, webkit, mozilla

My CSS3 animation doesn't work in Firefox and Safari though in Chrome.
I am using this code for executing the animation:

```
html {
    background:#262930 url('./images/pw_maze_black.png') no-repeat left top fixed;
    background-size:cover;

    animation:slides 60s; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation:slides 60s; 
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation:slides 60s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
```

And this is the animation itself (for each browser):

```
@keyframes slides
{
0%   {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/1.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
6%   {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/1.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
12%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/2.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
18%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/2.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
25%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/3.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
31%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/3.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
37%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/4.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
43%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/4.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
50%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/5.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
56%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/5.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
62%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/6.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
68%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/6.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
75%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/7.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
81%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/7.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
87%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/8.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
93%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/8.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
100% {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/1.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
}
@-moz-keyframes slides /* Firefox */
{
0%   {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/1.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
6%   {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/1.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
12%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/2.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
18%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/2.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
25%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/3.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
31%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/3.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
37%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/4.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
43%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/4.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
50%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/5.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
56%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/5.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
62%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/6.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
68%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/6.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
75%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/7.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
81%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/7.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
87%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/8.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
93%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/8.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
100% {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/1.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes slides /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/1.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
6%   {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/1.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
12%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/2.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
18%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/2.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
25%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/3.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
31%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/3.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
37%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/4.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
43%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/4.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
50%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/5.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
56%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/5.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
62%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/6.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
68%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/6.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
75%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/7.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
81%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/7.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
87%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/8.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
93%  {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/8.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
100% {background:url('./images/addix/slide_bg/1.jpg') no-repeat top center;}
}
```

Is it my fault or Firefox and Safaris?

EDIT: Link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AF4Ce/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason it might not be working in Firefox is the order of your animation with the pre-fixes.  Always put the un-prefixed version last, this will allow the browser to always try implementing that version last.  This is good because sometimes the prefixed version can still have some behavior linked to it, even if the browser has moved on to using un-prefixed versions.

But this is more of a suggestion than an answer as I don't know if it will fix it.  You might want to get your code into a JSFiddle (along with the image) so that others can see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok so I played around with the fiddle and was able to confirm that nothing is happening on FireFox.  I was able to add a border-color to the html element and in the -moz keyframes change the color of it and see it animate.  Which tells us something is wrong with the image.

After some searching I came across this answer and it just might not be possible in FF.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685133/background-image-for-firefox-in-css3-animations

Looks like you might need a Javascript fallback.